# scan input string and store words in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am writing a C program in which i want to scan an user given input like this:

"Hello how are you" (One single line without quotes)

and then each of this word should in an user defined array
like
a[0]=Hello
a[1]=how
a[2]=are
a[3]=you

here is code link https://github.com/fzx-314/learning/blob/master/text.C
function i am using for scanning input is

```
    j=0;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",&a[j][i]);
    }
```

Here is function i am using to print contents of array

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        printf("%s\t",a[i][j]);
```

getting run time error

Comment: Too many issues, re-read a C book first.

Comment: let me see full code

Comment: https://github.com/fzx-314/learning/blob/master/text.C

Comment: Try using two/multidimensional array

Comment: That code doesn't print anything.

Comment: i have given code link in comment above @melpomene

Comment: String in `C` is itself a `1D` array. If you want to store in mentioned way, `2D` char need to be used.

Comment: try `char a[4][10]; for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){ scanf("%9s", a[i]); printf("a[%d]=%s\n", i, a[i]); }`

Comment: @KevalMalde Your code should be in the question, not behind a link in the comments: [mcve]

Comment: @melpomene i got it i didn't knew i am new here sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: No need to apogolize. Instead, read the link provided, and [edit] your question and add missing information.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY still giving run time error

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. It is also difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  .Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, and your question to give a more complete description of the exact error you get when you run it..  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: @KevalMalde I don't get run time error. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/20JBgC)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY when i am integrating this in my code it is giving error

Comment: Even if you use 2D-Array like `char a[n][m];`, `printf("%s", a[i][j])` is wrong Because type of `a[i][j]` is `char`, not `char*`.  A problem arises because `%s` of `printf`  requires `char*`.

Comment: so what you suggest? what should i do? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `printf("%s\n", a[i]);`. I already wrote it (as `printf("a[%d]=%s\n", i, a[i]);`).

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to store two-dimensional char array. Code should be like

```
  char a[4][10];
  for(i=0;i<4;++i){
    gets(a[i]);
  }
```

It will get 4 strings and store them in different rows.

And they can be accessed in same way you mentioned

Comment: Never use `gets`.